# str_replace for distinct word

Tags: php, string

suppose I have `$str="nikparsa neginnikparsa somenikparsa"`
when I use

```
$str= str_replace('nikparsa', 'nik parsa', $str);
echo $str;
```

It will replace neginnikparsa with neginnik parsa too

I just want to replace when nikparsa is a **distinct word**

I mean like \bnikparsa\b in pregmatch but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Apart from seeing simshaun's answer, you could google it and figure it out yourself. That's a useful exercise

Comment: Yeah Thanks I really didn't know about preg_replace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\bnikparsa\b/i', 'nik parsa', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really don't want to use preg_replace, then:

```
substr( str_replace( ' stackoverflow ', '  do you see the apples?  ', " $str "), 1, -1 );
```

Read the comments about its limitations :)

Comment: This won't replace words at the end of the sentence.

Comment: And when my string is `stackoverflow woohoo stackoverflow!`?

Comment: It's true, but I think this is the maximum you can do with `str_replace` :)