# Replace whole word only with or without regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace occurances of whole words in a string. There are similar questions here at SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682629/str-replace-match-whole-word-only).

Answers to all these questions recommend using regex like this:

```
$needle = "a";
$haystack = "oh my dear a";
$haystack = preg_replace("/$needle\b/", 'God', $haystack);
echo $haystack;
```

This works good for whole words -  echoes `oh my dear God`

But if I replace `a` with `a.` in both needle and haystack, i;e

```
$needle = "a.";
$haystack = "oh my dear a.";
```

the output becomes `oh my deGod a.` because  `.` gets evaluated as regex.

I would want  `a.` to be replaced by `God` with or without regex.

Comment: you would escape the full stop

Comment: @Dagon escaping . in needle gives the output - oh my dear a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` refers only to word boundaries in an ASCII perception. Also `.` is a character of special meaning in regular expression — meaning "match any single character (*except newline*)"

If the "needle" may contain special characters, use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) and create [**DIY**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#diy) boundaries.

> `preg_quote()` takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

```
$str = preg_replace("~(?<=^| )" . preg_quote($needle, "~") . "(?= |$)~", 'God', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will give you an inspiration...

```
$haystack="oh my dear a." ;
$needle="a" ;
$hout=$haystack ;
$hout=~ s/\b$needle\b\./God/g ;

print "$haystack $needle $hout\n";
```

...produces this output...

```
oh my dear a. a oh my dear God
```

This works in perl. Sorry, my php is way rusty.